# Show $result->address in INPUT and update if input is not equal to $result->address

Tags: php, post

A data field is defined as `$field` in this example.

I have a form to **POST** all changed or added fields.

```
$result->address = 'Mainstreet 12'
```

I show it with :

```
<input type="text" name="address placeholder='. __('address', 'agent-plugin').'" value="'.$result->address.'" /></div>
```

But I also want to update the field if necessary. How to do this? Something like this?

```
($result->address > 0 ? $_POST['address'] : '' )
```

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: No. it is only an idea. Have to setup the update and insert of the form. But I did not know if my idea is working. Have not much experience.

Comment: *"But I also want to update the field if **necessary**."* - Use a conditional statement then. I.e.: `if(empty($var)){ echo "mandatory"; }` if that's what you are asking, You can also add `required` to the input, being HTML5. But the POST array needs to match the name attribute.

Comment: hmm do not understand this. I miss the $_POST of that field.

Comment: Why don't you try it and let us know if it doesn't work?

Comment: Just tried it but field stays empty and in the $_POST I get not back the new input. ($result->commerce_number != "" ? $_POST['commerce_number'] : ''

Comment: WIth this I see the correct data but it is not updated means $_POST stays empty: ($_POST['commerce_number'] != "" ? $result->commerce_number : $result->commerce_number )

Comment: I solved this: $uid ? $result->company_email: '' )